# Insert a break tag inside <span> using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I need to put a break tag after `<span>`. My span tags are inside of the `<li>` tag.

```
<li><span><a href=""></a></span><span>some text</span> <li>
```

I want to put a break tag where `<span>` contains the anchor tag.

Please tell me how to find the `<span>` tag in the code and add the break tag using JQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("li span:has(a)").after("<br/>");
```

***Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/LkeVE/1*

Answer (score 1):

Use `insertAfter` along with `:has` to check if `span` has `a`

```
$('li span:has(a)').insertAfter("<br />")
```

Comment: but i think this will apply after whole li tag.. i want to add this after that Span tag which contains acnhor tag.

Comment: Yes @saadk, I just missed that part o question, updated my answer check if it serves the purpose.

Comment: here it is what i wrote in my code

    $(document).ready(function(){
   
   $("#ticker ul li span:has(a)").insertAfter("<br/>");
   
 )};

But it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('span').after('<br />');
```